How do I find general solutions to trig equations with multiple different trig functions
I'm making this post because I keep running into problems like:
$10\sin{x}-4\sqrt{3}\cos{x}=1$
and whenever I try to solve for them I always end up getting 2 solutions since I'm squaring both sides and substituting in $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=1$.
The problem arises when I try to generalise these solutions. I get that one of the solutions is an extra solution which I can ignore but I don't know how to generalise the other one.
In this case, one of the solutions is $\sin{x}=47/74$ so I try to generalise it as $x=n\pi+(-1)^n\arcsin{47/74}$ which is wrong because it only works for even n.
Any help is appreciated.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, please see Sine and Cosine Linear Combinations.

After squaring, some of the $x$s you get are from $10\sin x - 4\sqrt3\cos x = -1$.
